# Androidplot couldnt capture screenshot

Tags: androidplot

When i try and take a screenshot of my activity that uses Androidplot i get a 'Could'nt capture capture screenshot - storage may be in use' message. I am able to take a screenshot perfectly if the Androidplot graph is not placed on the activity.

```
private void renderAndroidPlot()
{
    // on ICS+ devices :-)
    getActivity().getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);

    // initialize our XYPlot reference:
    plot = (XYPlot) getView().findViewById(R.id.mySimpleXYPlot);

    // Create a couple arrays of y-values to plot:
    Number[] series1Numbers =   getGraphData();

    // Turn the above arrays into XYSeries':
    XYSeries series1 = new SimpleXYSeries(
            Arrays.asList(series1Numbers),          // SimpleXYSeries takes a List so turn our array into a List
            SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.XY_VALS_INTERLEAVED, // Y_VALS_ONLY means use the element index as the x value
            "Series1");                             // Set the display title of the series


    // add a new series' to the xyplot:
    plot.getGraphWidget().getGridBackgroundPaint().setColor(Color.WHITE);
    plot.getGraphWidget().getBackgroundPaint().setColor(Color.WHITE);
    plot.setBorderStyle(Plot.BorderStyle.NONE, null, null);

    Paint lineFill = new Paint();
    lineFill.setAlpha(200);
    lineFill.setShader(new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 250, Color.WHITE, Color.parseColor("#99E6B1"), Shader.TileMode.MIRROR));
    LineAndPointFormatter formatter  = new LineAndPointFormatter(Color.rgb(0, 0,0), null, null,null);
    formatter.setFillPaint(lineFill);

    plot.setPlotMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
    plot.setPlotPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);

    plot.getGraphWidget().setMarginTop(30);
    plot.getGraphWidget().setMarginRight(50);
    plot.getGraphWidget().setMarginLeft(50);
    plot.getGraphWidget().setMarginBottom(50);



    plot.getGraphWidget().getDomainLabelPaint().setColor(Color.BLACK);
    plot.getGraphWidget().getRangeLabelPaint().setColor(Color.BLACK);

    plot.getGraphWidget().getDomainOriginLabelPaint().setColor(Color.BLACK);
    plot.getGraphWidget().getDomainOriginLinePaint().setColor(Color.BLACK);
    plot.getGraphWidget().getRangeOriginLinePaint().setColor(Color.BLACK);


    // reduce the number of range labels
    plot.setTicksPerRangeLabel(3);
    plot.getGraphWidget().setDomainLabelOrientation(0);

    //Remove legend
    plot.getLayoutManager().remove(plot.getLegendWidget());
    //plot.getLayoutManager().remove(plot.getDomainLabelWidget());
    plot.getLayoutManager().remove(plot.getRangeLabelWidget());
    plot.getLayoutManager().remove(plot.getTitleWidget());

    plot.setDomainStep(XYStepMode.SUBDIVIDE, 6);

    plot.addSeries(series1, formatter); //new LineAndPointFormatter(Color.parseColor("#2E64FE"), null, null, null));



}
```

Comment: can u show some snap on code snippet?

Comment: have just updated my main query with the code - thank you.

Answer (score 1):

That's due to an unfortunate mistake in the sample code that included this line:

```
getActivity().getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

Remove that from your code and screen captures should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
// on ICS+ devices :-)
getActivity().getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

This funny little block is made so the user is unable to to take screenshots. Remove it, and you will be able to take screenshots.

Comment: Are you aware that this question was asked in 2014? Also your answer is same as another one already posted. Please, post late answers only if it is significantly different or if it improve others, already posted.